# Update Column of a Hive Table without using Sub query

Tags: hadoop, hive

This is a question regarding updating a new column in a Hive table.  Since I think Hive does not allow to update a column of an existing table using subqueries, I wanted to ask what will be the best way to achieve the following update operation.

I have the following two example tables:

Table A:

**KeyId ValId Val**
   W1    V1    10
   W2    V2    20

Table B:

**KeyId ValId Val**
   W1    V1    10
   W1    V1    30
   W1    V3    40
   W1    V4    50
   W2    V2    0
   W2    V2    50
   W2    V2    70
   W2    V4    80

I want to create another column in Table A, lets say avgVal that takes the KeyId and ValId in each row in Table A and takes the average of Val for those corresponding KeyId and ValId in Table B.  Thus, my final output table should look like:

Updated Table A:

**KeyId ValId Val   avgVal**
   W1    V1    10     20
   W2    V2    20     40

Please let me know if the question is not clear.

Comment: Do you even know if  your table is update-able?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to get aggregate values in table A from table B. In that case you cannot have "val" column in table A because after aggregation which val from table B do you expect in table A?

Assuming that  was genuine mistake, and you remove "val" column from table a, your insert statement for table a should look like this:

```
insert into table table_a select keyid,valid,avg(val) from table_b group by keyid,valid
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query to get avg of data in Table_B corresponding to row in table_A :-

```
    select t1.keyid, t1.valid , t1.val , avgval from table_A t1 left join 
(select keyid as k , valid as v, avg(val) as avgval from Table_B group by keyid,valid )temp
 on k=t1.keyid and t1.valid=v;
```

You have to check the table_A is updatable to change the schema else you can make other table to load the data.